# Doctrine, namespace and autoload entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine, autoload

I want to use Doctrine 2 in my project. I've some problems with it. I read the docs but probably I'm doing something wrong.

I want to autoload entities classes. And method from the docs is not working.

My bootstrap.php

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver;

$paths = array("../Entities");
$isDevMode = false;

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities','../Entities');
$classLoader->register();

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'dbname'   => 'xxx',
);

$driver = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver(new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader(),array('../Entities'));
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

I've got my model's classes in Entities directory. I've generated them using doctrine client. They looks OK. There are ids, setters, getters and namespace at the beginning.

/Entities/ArticleCat.php

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ArticleCat
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article_cat")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArticleCat
{
```

My script where I want to use doctrine:

```
<?php
  require_once 'bootstrap.php';

  $article = $em->find('ArticleCat', 21);
  echo $article->getName();
```

It's not working. It works only when I use it this way and I **remove namespace from Entity model**.

```
<?php
  require_once 'bootstrap.php';
  require_once 'Entities/ArticleCat.php'; //this line added (manual load)


  $article = $em->find('ArticleCat', 21);
  echo $article->getName();
```

What's the proper way of using doctrine and autoload entities? Why the namespace is a problem?

My errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' 
with message 'Class 'ArticleCat' does not exist' in 
/myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96
Stack trace: #0 /myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(40): 
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('ArticleCat') 
#1 /myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping
   /AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(267): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping
   \RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses('ArticleCat') 
#2 /myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping
   /AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(297): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping
   \AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses('ArticleCat') 
#3 /myproject/vendor/doc in /myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence
   /Mapping/MappingException.php on line 96
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20348484/637210 this can be helpful, you can add namespace alias and use it like "find('NS:ArticleCat', 21)"

Answer (score 2):

Try to use fully qualified class name with namespace.
When you've got error about **CG** proxy classes try to generate your proxy classes by running

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies
```

good luck!

Comment: @CommaToast, this is a shell script

Answer (score 2):

If you are using composer, you want to be sure that you have the following 'autoload' in your composer.json:

```
{
        "require": {
           ...
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-0": {"": "Entity/"}
        }
}
```

This fixed the problem for me.  I'm not using any namespace in my entity class though.  My composer.json lives in my inc directory and the Entity directory referenced here is at inc/Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've always used the `ClassLoader` when it comes to using namespaces. I've had so much trouble with it that I 'm using a sort configuration class with all the `path/to/src`'s I need.

E.g. if your path is `path/to/src` and your classname is `Entities\ArticleCat` then the directory structure for the location of the file `ArticleCat.php` is

```
src \
  Entities \
    ArticleCat.php
```

Now all you need to do is create a `ClassLoader` for `Entities`

```
$src = 'path/to/src'
$cl = new ClassLoader('Entities', $src);
$cl->register();
```

and class `ArticleCat` should now be available using the `EntityManager`

```
$articleCat = $em->getRepository('Entities\ArticleCat');
$article = $articleCat->find(21);
echo $article->getName();
```

or

```
$article = $em->find('Entities\ArticleCat', 21);
echo $article->getName();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `ClassLoader` has been deprecated now.

Comment: @JacobThomason how time flies by! ;)