# Doctrine2 Entity Namespace

Tags: configuration, doctrine-orm, namespaces, annotations, entity

i'm new to Doctrine2 and like to know how i can tell Doctrine which namespace my entities use.
My current configuration [is this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager).

All my entities are in namespace "project\entity".
So, everytime i want to obtain the entity "Color", i have to write:

```
$em->getRepository("project\\entity\\Color")
```

How can i configure Doctrine to always use namespace "project\entity"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can come close to what you want by using addEntityNamespace on your config object to create a namespace alias:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->addEntityNamespace('NS1', 'Project\Entity');

$colorRepo = $em->getRepository('NS1:Color');
```

Works for queries as well.

By the way, `"project\\entity\\Color"` can also be written as `'project\entity\Color'`.  I would also suggest capitalizing Project and Entity just to conform to standards.

Comment: you can add a Blank namespace alias "$em->getConfiguration()->addEntityNamespace('', 'Project\Entity');" and use it $colorRepo = $em->getRepository(':Color'); without error. For me it's like a default namespace. I didn't find another way to configure default entities namespace