# php doctrine class not found when using namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine, autoloader

I got stuck following the doctrine [getting started](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product).

Let me show you the code first.

**/bootstrap.php**

```
namespace MyApp;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require 'config/slim.php'; //Some config files it doesn't matter
require 'config/dependencies.php'; //Some config files it doesn't matter

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

$doctrineDbConfig = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => $config['db']['user'],
    'password' => $config['db']['pass'],
    'dbname' => $config['db']['dbname'],
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create(
    $doctrineDbConfig,
    Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(
        array(
            __DIR__ . "/config"
        ),
        $isDevMode = true
    )
);
```

**/cli-config.php**

```
require "bootstrap.php";
return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

As you see I am telling doctrine "my entity config file is under /config dir", this is the config file for the product entity:

**/config/Product.dcm.yml**

```
Product:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
```

So I run this command:

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

And I got this:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
Class 'Product' does not exist
```

Let me show you the "Product" class:

**/src/Entities/Product.php**

```
namespace MyApp; //If I delete this line, It works

class Product
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Of course I am using composer autoloader as you see in the bootstrap.php file:

**/composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\": ["src/", "src/Entities/"]
    }
}
```

I am mapping the namespace "MyApp". This is working fine when I request the app through the index.php, but it is not working when using the command line.

If I delete the namespace line in the Product.php class, then It works and doctrine finds the class.

I have already tryed using this mapping :

**/composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": ["src/", "src/Entities/"]
    }
}
```

And I have already tryed creating a namespace alias, after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241917/doctrine-namespace-and-autoload-entities)

Could you please give some advice on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've found the solution... maybe a newbie one, I don't know.
I would appreciate if somebody please could validate this.

I've just added:

Fully qualified name in the config file name like this:

```
MyApp.Product.dcm.yml
```

I use the fully qualified name into the config file like this:

```
MyApp\Product:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
```